# Weird implicit convert issue in spark 1.6 of scala 2.10

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following is the sample code, it only happens when I put these 2 pieces of code together into spark shell. And it also only happens for spark 1.6 and scala 2.10. I guess it is issues of scala 2.10. Does anyone know the root cause. Thanks

```
case class Bank(
  age: Integer,
  job: String,
  marital: String,
  education: String,
  balance: Integer
)

val bank = 
  bankText.
    map(s => s.split(";")).
    filter(s => s(0) != "\"age\"").
    map(
      s =>
        Bank(
          s(0).toInt,
          s(1).replaceAll("\"", ""),
          s(2).replaceAll("\"", ""),
          s(3).replaceAll("\"", ""),
          s(5).replaceAll("\"", "").toInt
        )
    ).toDF()
```

Error:

```
error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Bank]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDF'?
       ).toDF()
         ^
```

Comment: The snippet you shared does not include, but I imagine you already imported the `spark.implicits._`, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704831/value-todf-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark-rdd-rdd) and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734663/issue-with-todf-value-todf-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark-rdd-rdd and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839984/value-todf-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark-rdd-rddlong-org-apache-spark-m

Comment: yes, it is imported by spark-shell

Answer (score 2):

This is an unresolved issue with implicits. `.toDF()` defined in `DatasetHolder` in spark source.

Move case class outside of the method where you are trying to `toDF`,

```
case class Bank(???)
```

Then, in your method,

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
val rdd: RDD[Bank] = ???

rdd.toDF()
```

Note, use `toDF` with braces.

More info on this here: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6649

Comment: do mark it as accepted if it helped. thanks